# Getting a "true" object from a proxy object in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine uses proxy objects to represent related objects in order to facilitate lazy loading. This is a really cool feature, but its causing an issue with something I am trying to accomplish.

I have customized my user object so that they are all required to be related to a different object, which I will call city. This relationship is working fine.

I have a form that my user fills out to generate another object, street. Street is also related to the city object. Instead of having my user select the city when they fill out the form, I want to automatically set it before I persist the object to my database.

I tried using `$event->setCity($user->getCity())`, but since $user->getCity() returns a proxy object, this generates an error. Is there a function I can call from the proxy object to get the real one?

*Note: I am aware I can create a custom query with a join to force doctrine to actually load the related object, but since this is the user (using FOSUserBundle) that would be difficult to do properly.*

Comment: I think this is supposed to work, even if `$user->getCity()` returns a proxy object, because proxy objects should behave just like true objects. Could you show us the error you're getting?

Comment: As gregOire says, the proxy object inherits from the city object. What kind of error are you receiving? When Doctrine persists relations these are always proxy objects.

Comment: Just noticed my issue, I got the namespace of my city class wrong in my entity class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 23):

This is unlikely to help in the specific instance for the question, since you're relying on a third-party module, but you can prevent the lazy loading by setting the "fetch mode" for your entity to "EAGER".

```
User:
    ManyToOne:
        city:
            fetch: EAGER
```

This can also be handled by annotations:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity="city", fetch="EAGER")
@JoinColumn(name="city", referencedColumnName="id")
```

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytoone

None of the other answers I've seen here worked for me.

Comment: this solved 'The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object', when saving instances in _SESSION

Comment: Wonderful, it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:** *As mention by @flu this approach don't return the "true" object. However it can be useful in case if you need the data from the object. 
Then, you can just get the real object from ObjectManager by some of identity.*

---

We can use __load() method from Proxy interface

```
$proxyObject->__load();
```

Comment: While it might be useful, this doesn't answer the OP's question because `Proxy::__load()` returns `void` and `$proxyObject` is still a proxy after calling `$proxyObject->__load();` so this doesn't return the *true* object from the proxy.

Comment: it didn't get the true object. it just loading all the entity value.

Answer (score 7):

You get an unique instance of an entity from Doctrine. If you request it two times, you'll always get the same object.

As a consequence, if your entity is lazy-loaded first (via a @ManyToOne somewhere for example), this entity instance will be a Proxy.

Example:

You have a User entity having a bidirectional `@OneToOne` on a Config entity...

**Case 1**

You request your User:

- you get a *real* instance of User
- $user->config will contain a Proxy

If later on you request the same Config entity in any piece of your app, you'll end up with that proxy.

**Case 2**

You request your Config and your User has never been imported before:

- you get a *real* instance of Config
- $config->user will contain a Proxy

If later on you request the same User entity in any piece of your app, you'll end up with that proxy.

---

All in all, querying again for the same entity will still end up to a proxy (which is an instance of your User anyway, because the generated proxy extends from it).

If you **really** need a second instance of your entity that is a `real` one (if some of your app logic does a `get_class` that you can't replace by `instanceof` for example), you can try to play with `$em->detach()` but it will be a nightmare (and thus your app may behave with even more magic than Doctrine already bring).

A solution (coming from my dark side, I assume) can be recreating a non-managed Entity manually.

```
public function getRealEntity($proxy)
{
    if ($proxy instanceof Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy) {
        $metadata              = $this->getManager()->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($proxy));
        $class                 = $metadata->getName();
        $entity                = new $class();
        $reflectionSourceClass = new \ReflectionClass($proxy);
        $reflectionTargetClass = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
        foreach ($metadata->getFieldNames() as $fieldName) {
            $reflectionPropertySource = $reflectionSourceClass->getProperty($fieldName);
            $reflectionPropertySource->setAccessible(true);
            $reflectionPropertyTarget = $reflectionTargetClass->getProperty($fieldName);
            $reflectionPropertyTarget->setAccessible(true);
            $reflectionPropertyTarget->setValue($entity, $reflectionPropertySource->getValue($proxy));
        }

        return $entity;
    }

    return $proxy;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, using `ClassMetadata::getFieldValue` and `ClassMetadata::setFieldValue` would simplify your `getRealEntity`

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

### Context:

**All** my entities have `id` property and `getId()` method

---

### Solution:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// 1 -> get the proxy object class name
$proxy_class_name = get_class($proxyObject);

// 2 -> get the real object class name
$class_name = $em->getClassMetadata($proxy_class_name)->rootEntityName;

// 3 -> get the real object
$object = $em->find($class_name, $proxyObject->getId());
```

---

### Problem:

This solution don't work if `id` property and `getId()` method are in a `Trait` class

I hope that it can help someone

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit nasty workaround that issue :

```
// $proxyObject = ...

$em->detach($proxyObject);
$entityObject = $em->find(<ENTITY_CLASS>, $proxyObject->getId());

// now you have real entity and not the proxy (entityObject instead of proxyObject)
```

after that you can replace proxy reference if you need to have it inside other entities

Answer (score 1):

@mustaccio, @Heather Orr

I had this problem. Thanks for idea,

This is the code:

```php
// $object is a Proxy class
$objectClass = get_class($object);
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($objectClass);

// Make sure we are not using a Proxy class
if ($obj instanceof Proxy) {
    $reflClass = $reflClass->getParentClass();
}
```

Another way, if you just need to read annotations:

```php
// $object is a Proxy class
$objectClass = get_class($object);
$classMetadata = $this->em->getClassMetadata($objectClass);

foreach ($classMetadata->getReflectionProperties() as $property) {
    $annotation = $this->annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotation($property, YOUR_ANNOTATION::class)
}
```

Not absolutely related to original question, but I hope this will help some people...

Answer (score 0):

Doctrines lazy loading is very good at its job, and will replace a proxy object with a real one as soon as you try to use it or any of its properties. If you are having issues due to the proxy objects (like I did in my question) you most probably have an error in your model.

That said, you can tell doctrine to pull all the related data by telling it to "hydrate":
`$query->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony [`PropertyNormalizer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/PropertyNormalizer.php) gets around this issue using the `ReflectionClass` [`getParent`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) method. If you need to inspect the object, as for a normalizer, rather than just use the `->get` methods, you should be able to use a similar approach.

It appears the Proxy has a parent of the actual entity, which is why instanceof still works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to extend the `Reflection Hydrator` and use the new class as Hal extractor params, for complex entities.

You can find the code here:

[Synergy of proxy object of doctrine and zend expressive hal](https://discourse.zendframework.com/t/synergy-of-proxy-object-of-doctrine-and-zend-expressive-hal/575/7?u=fancybuddy)

probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you first used `$em->getReference` and then `$em->find`, then the result will be a _proxy.
I recommend using:

```
 createQueryBuilder ... ->getQuery()
    ->setHint (Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```