# Doctrine oneToMany relationship results in null for foreign key on inverse entity when serializing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

> *Relevant information: I'm using Symfony 2.8.x, Doctrine 2.4.8 and JMSSerializerBundle 1.0.*

A `Resource` can have many `Experiences`. I'm making an **API Call** to retrieve a `Resource` and all associated `Experience`s.

However, the JSON I get back contains a `null` on `$resource` on the `Experience` entity.

I'm using the the following method to retrieve the `Resource`:

```
$this->findBy([], [], $limit, $offset);
```

I don't believe this should be an issue because I've tried setting the fetch mode to `EAGER` directly in the annotations - this still hasn't worked. I've also cleared the cache.

### Resource.orm.yml

```
oneToMany:
    experiences:
        targetEntity: Experience
        mappedBy: resource
        fetch: EAGER
```

### Experience.orm.yml

```
resource:
    targetEntity: Resource
    inversedBy: experiences
    joinColumn:
        name: resource_id
        referencedColumnName: id
        fetch: EAGER
    fetch: EAGER
```

*See I've tried ALL the eager fetches!!*

### Response

The response I get when making an API request for this json:

```
{
    "resources": [{
        "id": 1,
        # SNIP #
        "experiences": [{
            "resource": null,
            "id": 1,
            # SNIP #
        }]
    }]
}
```

*Note the null for resource!*

Here's why I think it's a problem with lazy loading: the collection is an instance of `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` instead of just an array as I expect:

[image]

**Why is this null??** What is my problem? Have I:

- Messed up the relationship configuration and this isn't actually anything to do with lazy loading
- Placed lazy loading in the wrong place
- Misunderstood and this is a *good* thing because of recursion?
- Something else retarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the normal behavior for the API and its Serializer (model to JSON transformation).

Why would you need `experiences.resource` to be filled actually ? You already have it on the root level of the JSON.

If you still want experiences to fully contain their resource, you probably have to configure the Serializer and force it to go 1 step deeper in serialization. But most of the time, Serializers are configured this way to avoid infinite cycles (resource containing its experiences, containing its resource, containing its experiences, and so on..

Comment: Yeah I thought this might be something to do with avoiding that recursion (as one of my bullet points suggets)..

Comment: if your API is based on Symfony too, it probably uses the native Serializer or JMS Serializer. In both cases, I'm pretty sure you can configure the level of recursion for serialization. But do it only if you really need to. Most of the time, the default recursion level fits common needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to upgrade Doctrine 2.4.8 to 2.5

[Doctrine2 in ZF2 - DQL gives different result than findOneBy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677533/doctrine2-in-zf2-dql-gives-different-result-than-findoneby-method)

```
> "doctrine/doctrine-module":"dev-master",
> "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
> "doctrine/dbal":"2.5.*@dev",
> "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev",
```

[UPDATE]

[Getting a "true" object from a proxy object in doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337754/getting-a-true-object-from-a-proxy-object-in-doctrine2)

Comment: Tried updating to `2.5.5` and cleared the cache, no change :-(

Comment: Have you tried to use EAGER directly in the query like the link ?

Answer (score 0):

One away to force Doctrine retrieve all related entities is creating a dql containing this entities.

```
$dql = "Select r, e From \MyNamespace\ToEntity\Resource r 
         Join r.experiences e";

$entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
```