# Doctrine prevent error on OneToOne association where record doesn't exist in database

Tags: doctrine-orm, laravel-doctrine

## Problem

I'm trying to create a OneToOne association in a Laravel app using Doctrine. When trying to access the association I'm getting this error.

`Entity of type 'Status' for IDs clientId(1) was not found`

## Versions:

### Doctrine: `2.7.5`

### Laravel: `7.30.4`

---

## Code:

#### Client Class

```
 <?php

namespace App\Client;

use App\Person\Person;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Client
 * @package App\Client
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 */
class Client extends Person
{

    /**
     * @var Status
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Status", mappedBy="client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="client_id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $status;


    /**
     * @return Status
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

#### Status Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Client\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Status
 * @package App\Client\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="status_view")
 */
class Status
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $clientId;

    /**
     * @var \App\Client\Client
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Client\Client", inversedBy="staus")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string")
     */
    protected $status;
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

#### Calling Code

```
$client->getStatus()->getStatus()
```

---

## What I've tried/Answers I've looked at

- [Entity of type 'AppBundle\Entity\User' for IDs id(155) was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615232/entity-of-type-appbundle-entity-user-for-ids-id155-was-not-found) - I'm not using a Doctrine filter, nor DQL.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416542/9530790 - This works, with a few tweaks, by swallowing up the exception, but it feels more like a hack when the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn) say `nullable` should work.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21887344/9530790 - This states `nullable` should work but it doesn't.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744449/9530790 - Same question different ans. States that Doctrine doesn't support zero-to-one associations, but `nullable` I believe should be what solves that, but for my problem it's not working. Also there's no link to the docs stating where Zero to one is not supported.
- I believe that adding `fetch="EAGER"` should fix the null issue as elsewhere in our app that works, but when I add that I get an different Doctrine error `spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given`, which again has to do with the association not existing.
- "Well why aren't you experiencing the above error with your other associations". Great question! After a deep underwater excursion into the Doctrine code, I believe the reason is because those associations are nested and for some reason (I'm not sure why), when nested, the `spl_object_hash` function, in class `UnitOfWork` is not called.

---

## Additional Notes:

- This is what the object looks like when calling `$client->getStatus()`, before it errors on the next `->getStatus()` call.

  ```
  DoctrineProxies\__CG__\App\Client\Entity\Status {#2011
       +__isInitialized__: false
       #clientId: 4
       #client: null
       #status: null
       …2
  }
  ```
- You can see it's a `Client` Proxy object that's created not a 'true' object, this is why it errors (with Entity of type 'Status' for IDs clientId(1) was not found) when not using `fetch="EAGER"`, since eager loads a true object. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427442/9530790)
- This code below in the Proxy object is the what causes the above error. Which is why I can't do a `try catch` in the parent ('true' `Client` class), since it errors before calling the parent.

  ```
   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public function getStatus()
   {

       $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getStatus', []);

       return parent::getStatus();
   }
  ```

## Question:

**Why is `nullable=true` not working as expected, and what should/can I do to make it work?**